# Posting through jQuery yields undefined characters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

When I try to post through jQuery it yields undefined characters. I'm using this jQuery code;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#status_submit").on('click', function()
    {
        var message = $( "#message" ).val();
        var uid = $( "#uid" ).val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type : "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url : "pro_profile.php?action=do_post_status",
            data : "message="+message+"&uid="+uid,
            success : function(response)
            {
                $('#show_custom_status').hide().html(response).fadeIn("slow");
                document.getElementById('message').value = '';
                document.getElementById('show_post_status').hide();
                //alert("Status has been posted successfully.");
            },
            error : function(response)
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It does posts the message correctly but if I use language other then English then it shows the characters like this;

[image]

The PHP I used is;

```
    $insert_array = array(
        "uid" => $uid,
        "message" => $db->escape_string($mybb->input['message']),
        "dateline" => TIME_NOW
    );
    $db->insert_query("pp_status", $insert_array);
```

So its fine as far as code is concerned.

Please help!

Comment: which type and Collation you are using for message field?

Comment: The `type` is `text` and `collation` is `latin1_swedish_ci`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change database collation from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci`

Other code seems correct.